# Consulta SQL server agrupada

Tags: sql-server

como ven en la imagen es el resultado de la tabla pero los registros sombreados son el mismo producto de ese mismo día , quisiera hacer la consulta que si el mismo día tiene el mismo producto se sume la cantidad y por ende el importe  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CON ESTA CONSULTA LLENO LA TABLA ....

```
select d.IDCLIENTE,d.FECHADOC,dv.CANTIDAD,p.NOMBRE,dv.PRECIO,dv.IMPORTE,0
                from DETALLE_DOCUMENTO_VENTA dv
                inner join PRODUCTO p on dv.CodProducto=p.IDPRODUCTO
                inner join DOCUMENTO_VENTA d on d.NROVENTA=dv.NROVENTA
                where d.IDCLIENTE='0000000021'

  
select IDCLIENTE,FECHA,1 AS CANTIDAD,('DEPOSITO -'+ RTRIM(TIPO) +'-'+ RTRIM(OBSER)) AS NOMBRE, MONTO,0,(MONTO*-1)  
   from PAGO_CLIENTE where PAGO_CLIENTE.IDCLIENTE='0000000021' AND PAGO_CLIENTE.estado='VIGENTE'
```

Comment: Hola, porfavor pon lo que haz intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: hola doc. , buenas así esta mi tabla

Comment: A ver te explico pq eres nuevo, es política del sitio que el que pregunta demuestre esfuerzo, por tanto pon la consulta que tienes hecha hasta ahora, no importa que este mal, edita tu pregunta y pon esta consulta

Comment: con esa consulta lleno  la tabla que se muestra

Comment: Ponlo como texto, no como imagen, edita la pregunta y pega el código

Comment: ahora si ya esta el codigo

Comment: Puedes probar agrupando utilizando [GROUP BY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) deberias agrupar por los campos que se repiten (CodigoCliente, Fecha, Nombre) y deberias sumar con [SUM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) los campos que necesitas (cantidad, importe, importe2). Intentalo, prueba y coloca aqui tu resultado y la consulta mas especifica (asi te podremos ayudar mejor, y tu puedes mejorar y especificar la pregunta original)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agrupando los productos y las fechas de venta, preba lo siguiente:

```
GROUP BY NOMBRE, FECHA
```

Eso puede ayudar a agrupar a como lo necesitas